# Change init script sequence number with update-rc.d

Tags: lubuntu, services, init.d

I've just installed apache2 in a LUbuntu 15.04 distribution using the command `apt-get install apache2`. By default the service is configured to start with a sequence number of 2:

```
ls -l /etc/rc?.d/*apache2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 17 sep  1 20:14 /etc/rc0.d/K01apache2 -> ../init.d/apache2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 17 sep  1 20:14 /etc/rc1.d/K01apache2 -> ../init.d/apache2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 17 sep  7 17:20 /etc/rc2.d/S02apache2 -> ../init.d/apache2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 17 sep  7 17:20 /etc/rc3.d/S02apache2 -> ../init.d/apache2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 17 sep  7 17:20 /etc/rc4.d/S02apache2 -> ../init.d/apache2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 17 sep  7 17:20 /etc/rc5.d/S02apache2 -> ../init.d/apache2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 17 sep  1 20:21 /etc/rc6.d/K01apache2 -> ../init.d/apache2
```

I'm trying to assign another sequence number for the apache2 service startup, using the command:

```
sudo update-rc.d apache2 defaults 91
```

The command doesn't return any error, but it changes nothing in the configuration. Any clue about what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.